# Evince does not open where I left off

Tags: evince

When I open a .pdf in evince, it always opens at the cover or the first page. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. "evince --version" returns "Gnome Document Viewer 42.0." Entering "evince" in the terminal returns,

```
(evince:14888): dbind-WARNING **: 09:21:39.799: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_1: Permission denied
```

If I enter "sudo evince" in the terminal, I get:

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

I'm at a loss what to try. I can't find any place in evince to set "preferences" or "settings."

Comment: Are you using WSL2?

Comment: No. What is WSL2? I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, installed on a 256gb thumb drive, plugged into a USB 3.0 socket.

Comment: @Procopius, this is a known issue, you can find the information [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evince doesn't save previous session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414822/evince-doesnt-save-previous-session)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using WSL2, make sure gvfs is installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gvfs
```

It seems that Evince needs gvfs installed to record where you last left off. If it doesn't work at first, reboot Ubuntu and try Evince again.

Comment: When I tried to install gvfs, I was told I already had the latest version. It doesn't help. I tried rebooting, and it still doesn't work.