# Evince doesn't save previous session

Tags: evince

Well im on 22.04 and things are unclear to me: evince doesn't remember session (window pos, page, zoom, etc)
I have been reading related posts about this but i don't understand. I only need to open my pdf and continue studing where i left.

Comment: This has been reported as [Launchpad bug #1969896](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896)

Answer (score 1):

See this currently unresolved [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896)

It won't work as you expect until the bug is fixed.

Comment: An update containing the fix has been released now.